# Save matplotlib plot with multiprocessing

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, plot, multiprocessing

The code I have been trying to apply multiprocessing is below.

```
#!/home/jaesoon/miniconda3/bin/python

import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

input_file = sys.argv[1]

df = pd.read_table(input_file, sep = "\t", header = None)

x = [] #approximate length is 50000000
y = []

for i in range(len(df[0])):
    x.append(str(df[0][i]))

for j in df[1]:
    y.append(j)


plt.plot(x, y)
plt.autoscale(enable = True)
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

Since the length of the input data is huge,
It takes a lot of time to draw just a simple plot.
(I have tested the script with smaller input, and it worked.)

Is there any way I can use multiprocessing in the script?

Thank you.

Comment: 1) you don't need either of those loops. 2) you don't actually have 50,000,000 pixels on your plot to show all of those points, so I recommend you aggregate the data in some way

Comment: Yes, appending is notoriously slow after a while.  Even faster would be to pre-allocate your array and do: `x=np.zeros(50_000_000); for i in range(): x[i]=str(df[0][i])`.  But my guess is that you could manage without the loop at all